# Resizes image but still with lots of bytes (UWP)

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp

I have this code that does image resizing of storage file:

```
var file = await ImageChooser.GetSelectedImageAsStorageFile();

using (var sourceStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
{
    int maxWidth = 500, maxHeight = 500;
    BitmapImage sourceImage = new BitmapImage();
    sourceImage.SetSource(sourceStream);
    var origHeight = sourceImage.PixelHeight;
    var origWidth = sourceImage.PixelWidth;
    var ratioX = maxWidth / (float)origWidth;
    var ratioY = maxHeight / (float)origHeight;
    var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);
    var newHeight = (uint)(origHeight * ratio);
    var newWidth = (uint)(origWidth * ratio);
    BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(sourceStream);
    BitmapTransform transform = new BitmapTransform() { ScaledHeight = newHeight, ScaledWidth = newWidth };
    PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(
    BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8,
    BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
    transform,
    ExifOrientationMode.RespectExifOrientation,
    ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage);

    using (var destinationStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        var propertySet = new BitmapPropertySet();
        var qualityValue = new BitmapTypedValue(0.3, PropertyType.Single);

        propertySet.Add("ImageQuality", qualityValue);

        BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, destinationStream, propertySet);
        encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied, newWidth, newHeight, 96, 96, pixelData.DetachPixelData());
        await encoder.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

The problem is that even resizing continues with the number of input bytes, for example if an image Enviu I 4MB it continues with those at the output to 4MB.

Answer (score 2):

You're writing the scaled image back to the original file meaning you're writing you scaled image to the first X bytes of the original file and leaving the rest untouched.

Either output to a new file or read the source file into memory and recreate the output file using the [`CreationCollisionOption` of `ReplaceExisting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.creationcollisionoption.aspx)

Comment: Exactly. Moving a `}` to restructure the `using`s should fix this.